# How do i combine checkbox values before sending to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I want to **store** the value of **checkboxes** in the **localStorage** with a delimiter of space. 
When I **check A** , **B** and press the save button it saves it as

```
["A","B"]
```

If I check A ,B and C and press the button the array becomes

```
["A","B","A","B","C"]
```

The output that I am trying to get is supposed to be

```
["A B","A B C"]
```

So this is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="A"> A<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="B"> B<br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="C"> C<br>
        <br><br>
        <a href="#" onclick="getValue();return false;">Get Value</a>

        <script>
            function getValue() {
            var myArray = !!localStorage.getItem('str') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('str')): [];
            var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.checks:checked');

            if(!checks.length) return; 

            for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            myArray.push(checks[i].value);
            }
            localStorage.setItem('str',JSON.stringify(myArray));
            console.log('str', myArray.join(' '));

            }

        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the current answers in a new array (`myChecks` in the demo), and add it to `myArray` before saving in `localStorage`.

**Note:** stackoverflow's snippet blocks the usage of localStorage. I've commented the lines that use localStorage, and I'm using an external `myArray` variable for the demo. To use in your code, uncomment the lines that read and write to localStorage, and remove `var myArray = []`.

```js
var myArray = []; // only for the demo

function getValue() {
  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.checks:checked');
  var myChecks = [];
  if (!checks.length) return;

  for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    myChecks.push(checks[i].value);
  }
  //var myArray = !!localStorage.getItem('str') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('str')) : [];
  
  myArray.push(myChecks.join(' '));
  
  //localStorage.setItem('str', JSON.stringify(myArray));
  console.log('str', JSON.stringify(myArray));

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="A"> A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="B"> B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="C"> C<br>
  <br><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="getValue();return false;">Get Value</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah its you again, thanks for your help.
P.S i was the guy last night(if we have the same timezone that is)

Comment: Welcome. I know :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't joining the array before you save it to local storage.

Comment: I just tried that sir, but it seems to not be working for me.
How do i do that ?